# Is there a way to make the default way a class is accessed a field within the class?

Tags: java, scala, opengl

I'm trying to write a wrapper for the following bit of scala code:

```
val vertBuffer: FloatBuffer = createFloatBuffer(vertex_positions.length)
vertBuffer.put(vertex_positions)
vertBuffer.flip()
```

However, the class will be used almost exclusively in things like this:

```
val vboId = glGenBuffers()
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid having to type something similar to

```
vertBufferWrapper.getWrapped
```

and be able to write just

```
vertBufferWrapper
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: But vertBufferWrapper is not the same type as vertBuffer.  How do you expect that to work?

Comment: When something receives a vertBufferWrapper, I want the wrapper to just deliver a vertBuffer, without field accessors, just for simplicity of code. Currently, I'll have to put vertBufferWrapper.vertBuffer (or get(), or whichever) everywhere I need a vertBuffer.

Edit: I suppose I could define vertBufferWrapper as vertBufferWrapper.get()?

Comment: `myVertBuffer = vertBufferWrapper.getVertBuffer()`.  Then use `myVertBuffer` in your subsequent code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store it in a wrapped class in the first place.  Just create a transformation function from the data structure you have to the one you need:

```
def createFlippedBuffer(vertex_positions: Positions) : FloatBuffer = {
  val vertBuffer: FloatBuffer = createFloatBuffer(vertex_positions.length)
  vertBuffer.put(vertex_positions)
  vertBuffer.flip()
  vertBuffer
}
```

It's not clear if you had other reasons to choose a wrapper in the first place, but another option is the [pimp my library](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example) feature, which allows you to add methods to existing classes without explicitly using a wrapper.

Comment: I'll take a look at pimp my library. The original data type is provided by java.nio, and is used by lwjgl to feed values into opengl functions without the risk of the GC mishandling memory. Thank you!